# Changing the value of String in Switch statement in Java

Tags: java, android, radio-button, switch-statement, android-radiogroup

I'm trying to change the value of a String data type inside a **switch statement** in **Android**. And that String is declared inside the same method in which the switch statement in declared, and I need to **change the value of the String** when the user **click on the Radio Button.**

```
public void CreateQuestion(View view) {

    String questionType = new String();
    RadioGroup questionTypeRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.questionTypeRadioGroup);
    questionTypeRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.true_false:
                    questionType = "True/False";
                    break;

                case R.id.mcqs:
                    questionType = "MCQs";
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As you write when onClick on your radio button so why you need checkChanged Listener.CheckChaneg only works when you change the type. you can set Click listener on each Radio Button. It will do your job.

Comment: What is the error? He doesn't recognize the string ? If yes, that's not because of the switch, that's because you're in an anonymous class that doesn't have access to the string you instanciated

Comment: why you call new String();? it's not a good practice and not needed

Comment: The real problem is that the switch statement is not executed at all, I made a Toast message in both the switch cases but neither Toast appeared??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U should declare your string globally

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public String questionType;

    ....

    public void CreateQuestion(View view) {
         questionType = "";
         questionTypeRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {
              switch (checkedId) {
                     case R.id.true_false:
                          questionType = "True/False";
                          break;

                      case R.id.mcqs:
                          questionType = "MCQs";
                          break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    ....

}
```

Comment: The real problem is that the switch statement is not executed at all, I made a Toast message in both the switch cases but neither Toast appeared??????

Comment: Are u sure that this id's are correct? R.id.true_false & R.id.mcqs, show your xml pls